# ngx-translate - Translate items synchronously

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ngx-translate

I have a component which takes an array of `MenuItem` objects:

```
<p-contextMenu [model]="contextMenuItems"></p-contextMenu>
```

I create these menu items in a function:

```
private createContextMenuItems(): MenuItem[] {
    let menuItems: MenuItem[] = [
      {
        id: 'play',
        label: 'Play'
        icon: 'pi pi-play',
      },
...
doSomeAdditionalWork(menuItems);
return menuItems;
```

After this is complete, I do some additional processing on these menu items and set `this.menuItems = this.createContextMenuItems()` to populate the component.

The problem I'm having is that the translate service is asynchronous:

```
this.translate.get('VOICEMAIL_INBOX.PLAY_VIEW').subscribe()
```

I am unsure how to set this up so that it translates prior to doing additional work and returning the set of `MenuItem[]` to the caller to bind to the component.  I have considered making the entire chain asynchronous and using something like `await firstValueFrom()` and handling these synchronously, but that requires I color the entire call chain as `async` and I am still unsure how to wait for it to resolve the translations before binding to the component.

`ngx-translate` does have an `instant()` method.  However this only returns the key when I use it, and not the translated value.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you never want to fight async behavior and instead embrace it. I find this [site](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree) a useful resource to determine what kind of async function I need for various situations. For this, I believe you can use a forkJoin combined with a map. Please see this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ylkaxd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). The key points here are as follows:

In parent component html:

```
<app-child [menu]="menu | async"></app-child>
```

In parent component ts:

```
this.buildMenu();
this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => this.buildMenu());
```

and:

```
private buildMenu(): void {
this.menu = forkJoin([
  this.translate.get('VOICEMAIL_INBOX.PLAY_VIEW'),
  this.translate.get('VOICEMAIL_INBOX.DELETE'),
]).pipe(
  map(([playTranslation, deleteTranslation]) => {
    const playMenu = {
      id: 'play',
      label: playTranslation,
      icon: 'pi pi-play',
    };
    const deleteMenu = {
      id: 'delete',
      label: deleteTranslation,
      icon: 'pi pi-delete',
    };
    return [playMenu, deleteMenu];
  })
);
```

}

In the child component html:

```
<div *ngFor="let menuItem of menu">
  <h2>{{ menuItem.label }}</h2>
</div>
```

In the child component ts:

```
@Input() menu: any[];
```

Comment: The problem here I that I don't have control over the context menu component, it is a `p-contextmenu` from PrimeNG.   The `MenItem[]` has to be fully translated prior to being bound in the template.

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, I completely missed this comment. 
But I think you were missing the point here. The menu observable that is referenced in "menu | async" will be translated and completed before it gets passed into the child component. If the issue is that the child component doesn't support waiting for the observable to complete (I think the menu input will be undefined until the async finishes), you can do something like "(menu | async) || []" to make it default to an empty array until the async finishes.